# Use plugin after getImage() in Magento 2

Tags: layout, blocks, plugin, magento2.2

I want to add text after image on product list page. For that I created plugin for **getImage()** function of `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php`

Plugin Code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{
    public function afterGetImage(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        $result .= 'Testing From Plugin';
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**But I'm getting this error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct::__construct() must be of the type array, object given

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove extend class and check it.

Comment: if I remove extended class it's shows this error `Argument 1 passed to Module\Model\Product::afterGetImage() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product, instance of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor given,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It create an Issue because return type of `getImage` is `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image` and you are trying to convert into string. I think by just appending the text you can not achieve your goal.

I am not sure what is your exact goal but I can assume that you need to add additional attribute to product Image attribute so you can use it in your `phtml` file. For that you can print the `$result->getData()` in your log file you can see that number of product Image attribute. So you can add your custom attribute by appending this data.

In log file I am getting,

```
array (
  'image_url' => 'My Product image URL,
  'width' => '240',
  'height' => '300',
  'label' => 'test',
  'ratio' => 1.25,
  'custom_attributes' => '',
  'resized_image_width' => 135,
  'resized_image_height' => 135,
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use with aroundPlugin and check,

```
 public function aroundGetImage(
            \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
            \Closure $proceed,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
            $imageId,
            $attributes = []
        ) {
            $result = $proceed($product, $imageId, $attributes);
            $newStr = 'Testing From Plugin';
            return $result. $newStr;
        }
```